# Just recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a macbook pro, except the camera everything works nice

Tags: 20.04, webcam, macbook-pro

Installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my MacBook pro.
Applications like Zoom, Gmeet, Teams, Skype shows 'No Device Found'.
Using a MacBook Pro 11, 4.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do a little bit of work to get the camera to work on your mid-2015 era MacBook Pro. Fortunately, it's not *too* difficult:

0. Install `git` on your machine if you do not already have it:
   `sudo apt-get install git`
1. Install three more tools:
   `sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio`
2. Clone the `facetimehd-firmware` repository to your machine:
   `git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git`
3. Enter the directory:
   `cd facetimehd-firmware`
4. Compile and install the firmware:

```
make
sudo make install
```

5. Return to your home directory with `cd ~`
6. Install a few more bits of software:
   `sudo apt-get install kmod libssl-dev checkinstall`
7. Clone the FaceTime HD driver to your machine:`git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git`
8. Enter the directory:
   `cd bcwc_pcie`
9. Compile and install the driver:

```
make
sudo make install
```

10. Make sure everything is hooked up:

```
sudo depmod
sudo modprobe -r bdc_pci
sudo modprobe facetimehd
```

11. Edit your `/etc/modules` file as `sudo`:
    `sudo vi /etc/modules`
12. Add this to the end of the file:

```
# Add FaceTimeHD drivers
facetimehd
```

13. Reboot

This should give you everything you need

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply....
It's working after following these steps
Thank you so much..

Comment: Sorry but it cant locate - xzcat and cpio in the commando, sudo apt-get install curl xzcat cpio. How do i do?